# Website to practice Java coding assignments for interview

Tags: java

I am looking for a website where I could practice Java coding assignments that you often get on job interviews. I mean those tasks where you need to calculate primitive numbers, implement some sorting, or do something with an Array, List or a Map. I'm quite experienced java developer, but such tasks can sometimes be tricky :)

Do you know any free websites that could help?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a constructive question for SO I'm afraid..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to [interviewstreet](http://www.interviewstreet.com). Companies often use it as first technical screen

Comment: I believe it's only for employers. I am looking for some site where I could practice. But Thank You anyway.

Comment: You can go to its sister site https://www.hackerrank.com/

Comment: yup, that's the kind of website I am looking for. Thank you